# multilingual web: php + mysql + cookies

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, multilingual

I have coded a multilingual web with php & mysql.
Now I've faced problems (mainly with robots, seo and search engines) 
because language chooser is based on **cookies**.

how it works now: user => index.php :

```
function cookies() {
 if (!isset($_COOKIE["lang"])){
 setcookie('lang','ukr', time()+(60*60*24*31)); 
 header('Location: index.php');  
}};
```

and outputting chosen language to every place it needed to be with the function:

```
function catSet($source, $link, $item){
 $item .= '_'. $_COOKIE['lang'];
 global $connection;
 $link = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $link);
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM  $source WHERE link_item = '". $link ."'");
if (!$result) { die("DB Query failed: " . mysql_error()); }
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
 echo $row[$item]; }}
```

What I want now is to have `$item .= '_'. $_COOKIE['lang'];` to be replaced with **constant** based on a user choice which would be readable by robots and search engines, so it's a must it's not a **cookie**.

I don't want to use **session**, because this way user have to re-choose language each time after session expires.

AFAIK there is no way to detect browsers language, to set it as default.

I see a way out to use [GET] variable instead, and pass it each time to other page, but how to store  this [GET] data if user come back next time (same problem as with sessions).

*I would appreciate any ideas and solutions :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use cookies to save user decision. When user visit your website without language in url (`GET`) but got cookie with selected language, redirect him to url with selection.

It'll allow you to use addresses with given language and also will allow user to just copy/past his current URL which will always lead him to his language version.

Comment: this way I have to make if/else check for `(!isset($_COOKIE["lang"]))` each time. User comes to page 1st time, let's say the default lang='eng', if user changes lang, next time I'll read cookie and give him back lang he chosen. BUT! Robots doesn't use cookies, it means they will always see only one=default lang?!

Comment: @A1exandr Like I said, redirect user and ignore cookie when value in get is set. Also in all links on webpage use that get variable. Eg. when incoming link had lang=en then every link on website will have that lang=en added.

Comment: I understand you. But what if value in get is set to default. Would robots crawl thru other languages?!

Comment: @A1exandr No, like in every other cases you have to provide urls to every language, eg. in top of the site, with flags to allow user to change language. This links also will allow robots to find other languages. Also it's good idea to create sitemap with all versions.

Comment: OK! For the moment I'll stay with this decision:

    if (!isset($_COOKIE["lang"])){
     global $lang;
     $lang = "ukr";
    }else{
     setcookie('lang','ukr', time()+(60*60*24*31));
     $lang = $_COOKIE["lang"]; };

Comment: Even better like this in case user coming back and chose lang before:

`if (!isset($_COOKIE["lang"])){
   global $lang;
   $lang = "ukr";
 }else{
  if (isset($_COOKIE["lang"])){
   $lang = $_COOKIE["lang"];
  }else{
  setcookie('lang','ukr', time()+(60*60*24*31));
  $lang = $_COOKIE["lang"];
 }};`

Comment: @A1exandr But don't forget that value from `$_GET['lang']` is more important than one from cookie. This way you'll allow viewing exact content from given url.

Answer (score 0):

For localization you can use gettext extension of PHP this uses .po and .mo file format for content translation. This will solve problem of SEO as well. All the contents loaded in memory of server in form of object and seen on browser as per requested language.
For more detail [read here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)

Comment: ok, that's an option, but I can edit mysql with webAdministration panel, I'm not sure if editing PO Files would be so easy.

Comment: @ElonThan - definitely SEO is completely another question, but in my case, I need robots to see all languages for the beginning.

Comment: @A1exandr We can edit .po file easily POEDIT or text editor, then we convert it into .mo that loaded into memory.

Comment: @PraveenDeshmukh ok, thanks, I'll learn this question. how does the users choice of language is stored?